# Rendering a view if item is done or contains a search term

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an if with nested conditions and end up with this ugly if:

```
if( !arg ||
                (typeof arg.search != 'undefined' && typeof arg.done == 'undefined' &&
                item.attributes.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.search.toLowerCase()) != -1) ||
                typeof arg.search != 'undefined' && typeof arg.done != 'undefined' &&
                (arg.done && item.attributes.done) || (!arg.done && !item.attributes.done) &&
                item.attributes.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.search.toLowerCase()) != -1
            ){
                renderView();
            }
```

This pice of code is actually working but I don't like the style of it. How can I improve this code to make it cleaner and more readable.

### In plain English

if `arg` is not passed **OR** 
if `arg.search` exist but `arg.done` is not exist and there is something similar to `arg.search` in `item.attributes.text` **OR**
if `arg.search` and `arg.done` exist and there is something similar to `arg.search` in `item.attributes.text` call that function.

Comment: You can get rid of the typeof checks and just check for undefined. `arg.search !== undefined`

Comment: @epascarello Yeah, you don't want to do that.  `typeof blah == 'undefined'` will **always** work.  But `blah == undefined` will only **usually** work.  http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2006/08/02/Define-undefined.aspx

Comment: @RossPatterson That's a silly reason. Your code might break if e.g. Math were redefined, but we don't worry about that. The serious reason to use typeof for testing undefined is that `typeof foo === 'undefined'` *does not throw if `foo` does not exist* and so can be used for testing. But that does not apply to property accesses, which do not throw on absence.

Comment: @KevinReid I wish I had a buck for every time I've found a variable called `undefined` in a JavaScript program.

Comment: Than redefine `undefined` yourself, it is not hard.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously there's no way I can try this out but you could organize your code in functions. Also I don't understand why this:

```
(arg.done && item.attributes.done) || (!arg.done && !item.attributes.done)
```

If both exist or don't exist seems trivial...What's the logic here?
I would do something like this:

```
var argExist = function () {

    var exist = true,
        isUdf = function (o) {
            return (typeof o === 'undefined') ? false : true;
        },
        atts = !!~item.attributes.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(arg.search.toLowerCase());

    if (!arg || ( !isUdf(arg.search) && isUdf(arg.done) && atts) ) {
        exist = false;
    }

    return exist;

};

if (!argExists()) { renderView(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what comments are for.  Leave the code as it is, and explain its intent with your "In Plain English" version.  But polish it up a bit, making it less boolean-logic-y - something more like "If we didn't get any arguments, or if we got a search that resembles this item, show it."

As an aside, your English version seems wrong, which is part of the reason why the text should describe its intent, not its process.  Translated to pure boolean, it reads:

```
!A | (B & !C & D) | (B & C & D)
```

but the code reads

```
!A | (!B & C & D) | (!B & !C & (E & F)) | ((!E & !E) & D)
```